# Why does Android 12 and room-paging now crash

Tags: android, android-room

I've updated my android application to target Android S and was made to add

```
api 'androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.0-beta01'
```

to my gradle build file.

Now my app crashes with

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.elsevier.funding.institutional, PID: 16031
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "java.lang.Object androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer.presentNewList(androidx.paging.NullPaddedList, androidx.paging.NullPaddedList, int, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0, kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)"
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(PagingDataDiffer.kt:151)
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$1$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:89)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:165)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataDiffer$collectFrom$2$invokeSuspend$$inlined$collect$1.emit(Collect.kt:135)
        at androidx.paging.PagingDataTransforms$map$$inlined$transform$1$2.emit(Collect.kt:138)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:62)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.access$emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:1)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt$emitAllImpl$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:69)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resumeUnconfined(DispatchedTask.kt:244)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:161)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.completeResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:513)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractChannel$ReceiveElement.completeResumeReceive(AbstractChannel.kt:908)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ArrayChannel.offerInternal(ArrayChannel.kt:83)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.channels.AbstractSendChannel.send(AbstractChannel.kt:134)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.doInitialLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:317)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot.access$doInitialLoad(PageFetcherSnapshot.kt:54)
        at androidx.paging.PageFetcherSnapshot$doInitialLoad$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix was to also increase paging `androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx` to `beta01`

```
api 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.0-beta01'
api 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0-beta01'
api 'androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.0-beta01'
api 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.1.0-beta01'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-beta01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem updating the library to beta  version `androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx` and using kotlin version 1.5.30

```
kotlin_version = '1.5.30'
room_version = '2.4.0'
paging_version = '3.1.0-beta01'
```

Comment: The answers provided on StackOverflow should be clear and should not be used to advise or seek help from someone else. Let us know your ideas in the comments.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31287929)